Should we merge "Part Identification" with "Identification"?
In the interests of feeding my taxonomy OCD, I was looking at the current part-identification tag, and felt its use was a little haphazard:
We have about 17 items tagged "Part Identification", compared with 74 tagged "Identification".
For some added context:

15 questions are also tagged with sets asking about Set Identification (especially after I added that to a few others)
13 questions are only tagged Identification (note that the query is running on an archived dataset which takes a while for that to update with the changes I made to clean up some of the questions)
5 questions are only tagged "Part Identification"

Currently our "Piece Information" wiki states:

Use identification for questions about unknown pieces or sets.


Do you think "Part Identification" stands on it's own?
Do we need something else to help distinguish "part identification" from "set identification"?
Should we create a similar "Set Identification" tag and remove "sets" from those questions instead?
If we create "Set Identification" should we then retire "Identification"?


In my mind, part of the reason that we can put multiple tags is so that we don't have to be super specific.  Set identification questions should be tagged with "set" and "identification".  Likewise, part identification questions should probably be tagged with "part" and "identification" or something similar.

@Nick2253 Agreed, but I'm not sure "Part" or "Element" really stand on their own. I guess "Sets" is really "Set Information" so is it ok to tag them "Piece Information" and "Identification" (which quite a few are anyway)

I forgot we had "Piece information" already.  That's probably the way to go.

I don't think a 'identification' tag is necessary given that almost every identification questions is clearly either about a part (or selection of parts) and a set.

I guess the idea was that we wanted the "identification" tag to exist to distinguish between questions asking about how a particular element should be used or has changed, compared with the "what is this part" questions - then people can mark "Identification" as an ignored tag, and not see them. Would you prefer a "Set Identification" tag and retire the Identification one?
